# Download dataframe as excel using FastAPI at custom location

Tags: html, python-3.x, fastapi

I am new to FastAPI and I need to understand if there is a way to download a dataframe in excel format at user selected location in their system. Below is the sample code I wrote but for downloading the dataframe as excel, I had to hardcode the system location in the code.

**main.py code :**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Form
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
import uvicorn
import pandas as pd

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="htmlDirectory")

class NameValues(BaseModel):
    Name : str = None

def save_to_excel(content, filename):
    file = content.to_excel(r"E:\PycharmProjects"+"\\"+filename+".xlsx", index=False)
    return file

@app.get("/home", response_class = HTMLResponse)
def home(request:Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("introduction.html", {"request": request})

@app.post("/displayDF")
async def handle_df(request: Request, Name: str = Form(...), action: str = Form(...)):
    if action == "Submit":
        test_list = [["Joe", 34, "Accounts", 10000], ["Jack", 34, "Chemistry", 20000]]
        data = pd.DataFrame(data=test_list, columns=["Name", "Age", "Dept.", "Salary"])

        return templates.TemplateResponse(
        'df_representation.html',
        {'request': request, 'data': data.to_html()}
        )
    if action == "Download":
        test_list = [["Joe", 34, "Accounts", 10000], ["Jack", 34, "Chemistry", 20000]]
        data = pd.DataFrame(data=test_list, columns=["Name", "Age", "Dept.", "Salary"])
        save_to_excel(data, Name)
        return "File Downloaded successfully"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('main:app', host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

**df_representation.html code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>displayDF</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>DataFrame representation:</h2>
<!-- You've to mark your data as safe,
    otherwise it'll be rendered as a string -->
    {{ data|safe }}

<form action="/displayDF" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Name">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Download">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**introduction.html code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Please enter a string in the space provided</h2>

<form action="/displayDF" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Name">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code works fine but the only problem is that I have hardcoded location in **save_to_excel** method in **main.py** file. I need to change the code in such a way that user could select the desired location in their system and let program know where they want the dataframe downloaded in excel format. Thanks in advance for all the help!!

Comment: Added HTML tag as I feel this could be solved by editing HTML code.